# How to exclude re-tweets in my twitter steam using tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, streaming, tweepy

Looking for some assistance with tweepy, please.

I'm attempting to remove retweeted entries in my stream but am not having much luck. The script i've made is attempting to stream tweets from a particular user (in this example @olympics) but end up getting mainly retweets.

Code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from tweepy import Stream, OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time
import json


# Add your own
access_token = ''
access_token_secret = ''
consumer_key = ''
consumer_secret = ''


class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
    
    # Twitter returns data in JSON format - we need to decode it first
        tweet = json.loads(data)
        print('@%s: %s' % (tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
        with open('fetched_tweets.csv','a') as tf:
            tf.writelines('%d,\"%s\",%s,%d,%d,\"%s\"\n' % (tweet['id'], tweet['created_at'], tweet['user']['screen_name'],
                                                           tweet['user']['followers_count'], tweet['user']['friends_count'],
                                                           tweet['text'].encode('ascii','ignore')#.replace('\n',' ', 100).replace(',',' ', 100)
                                                           ))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print(status_code)


auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(follow=["52422878"], is_async=True)
```

```
Sample output is
```

@FanaiMahriati: b'@Olympics @ittfworld '
@ArnHub: b'RT @Olympics: Tom Dumoulin of #NED takes #silver in the #CyclingRoad mens individual time trial.\n\n#StrongerTogether | #Tokyo2020 | @UCI_cy'
@ftw_cdhn: b'RT @Olympics: Its #gold for @rogla of #SLO in the #CyclingRoad mens individual time trial!\n\n#StrongerTogether | #Tokyo2020 | @UCI_cycling'
@ftw_cdhn: b'RT @Olympics: Tom Dumoulin of #NED takes #silver in the #CyclingRoad mens individual time trial.\n\n#StrongerTogether | #Tokyo2020 | @UCI_cy'
@Real_rafel20: b'RT @Olympics: Tom Dumoulin of #NED takes #silver in the #CyclingRoad mens individual time trial.\n\n#StrongerTogether | #Tokyo2020 | @UCI_cy'
@tezol_mutlu: b'@Olympics Bravo Tom, Bravo Dumoulin. Congratulation.'

Any help and suggestions are much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Just check the retweet status of the tweet:

```
class listener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        tweet = json.loads(data)

        # If the returned tweet object is NOT a retweet:
        if not tweet['retweeted_status']:
            print('@%s: %s' % (tweet['user']['screen_name'], tweet['text'].encode('ascii', 'ignore')))
            with open('fetched_tweets.csv','a') as tf:
                tf.writelines('%d,\"%s\",%s,%d,%d,\"%s\"\n' % (tweet['id'], tweet['created_at'], tweet['user']['screen_name'],
                                                            tweet['user']['followers_count'], tweet['user']['friends_count'],
                                                            tweet['text'].encode('ascii','ignore')#.replace('\n',' ', 100).replace(',',' ', 100)
                                                            ))
            return True
```